# Determine whether variable is ES2015 Map or plain old JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I’m writing a constructor for an ES2015 class that will accept either a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or a plain old JavaScript object. If the input argument is a Map, the constructor will just store it, but if it’s a JS object, it should convert it to a Map, via, say, `new Map(Object.keys(obj).map(k => [k, obj[k]]))`.

My question is: how can I safely tell whether an input argument is a Map or Object? I can test for a few Map-specific methods, but is there a more reliable and readable way? As far as I can tell, there’s no Map equivalent of `Array.isArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `instanceof Map` to test if it is a Map

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

```js
const map = new Map()
     ,obj = {}
console.log(map instanceof Map) // true
console.log(obj instanceof Map) // false
```

Also, you can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) if you want to convert an object to a Map:

```
new Map(Object.entries(obj))
```

Comment: `Object.entries` is not ES6.